# Bucketing top N results with an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pipeline

I am using pymongo to make some analytics on MongoDB.

In MongoDB there are 480000 json objects representing tweets made between March and April 2020 about Covid-19 virus.

In particular, these objects contain two fields:

1)"created_at", which represents the tweet's creation timestamp  (for example created_at : 2020-03-20T10:57:57.000+00:00 ) of type date;

2)"retweet_count",  which represents how many times the tweet is retweeted (for example "retweet_count:30");

I would make an aggregation pipeline which takes, for each day, the first 5000 json objects with the highest value of retweet_count.

The problem is that i don't undestand neither if i have to use a group clause, a match clause or a project clause (i am a newbie).

Here there is a try that i've done:

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timezone
from pymongo import MongoClient

client['Covid19']['tweets'].aggregate([
    {
        '$match' : {
            "created_at": { '$gte': datetime(2020, 3, 20), '$lt':  datetime(2020, 3, 21) } 
        }

    },
    {
        '$merge': {
            'into': 'tweets_filtered'
        }
    }
])

print(client['Covid19']['tweets_filtered'].count_documents({}))
```

This pipeline provides as result the tweets made from 20 March to 21 March, but i would generalize the process and take the first 5000 tweets for each day with the highest value of retweet_count.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the desired boundaries programmatically and use $bucket.

1. $sort input to achieve the desired ordering (most retweeted first).
2. $bucket to split the collection by day.
3. $push to move each document under the respective day.
4. $project with $slice to get the top X results.

Ruby sample using time, count and message fields:

```
require 'mongo'

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::WARN

client = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:14420'])
c = client['foo']


c.delete_many

10.times do |i|
  day_time = Time.now - i*86400
  100.times do |j|
    time = day_time + j*100
    count = rand*1000
    message = "message #{count}"

    c.insert_one(time: time, count: count, message: message)
  end
end


days = (-1..10).map { |i| Time.now - i*86400 }.reverse
pp c.aggregate([
  {'$sort' => {count: -1}},
  {'$bucket' => {groupBy: '$time', boundaries: days,
    output: {messages: {'$push' => '$$ROOT'}},
  }},
  {'$project' => {top_messages: {'$slice' => ['$messages', 5]}}},
]).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo answer using pandas:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

TOP_N_PER_DAY = 5000

# Perform the find with a filter; strip out the _id
tweets = db.tweets.find({ 'created_at': {'$gte': datetime(2020, 3, 20), '$lt':  datetime(2020, 3, 22) }}, {'_id': 0})

# Create a dataframe from the find
df = pd.DataFrame(list(tweets))

# Convert the datetime to a date only timeseries
df['date'] = df['created_at'].dt.date

# Group by date and sort by retweet count
df = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('retweet_count', ascending = False)).reset_index(drop=True)

# Take the top n per day
df = df.groupby('date').head(TOP_N_PER_DAY)

# Convert the pandas timeseries back to a datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Convert the dataframe into a list of dicts
records = df.to_dict('records')

# Insert the filtered tweets into a new collection
db.tweets_filtered.insert_many(records)
```